# File system operations from C programming and system command call

Tags: c, filesystems

I need operations like: 
`ls -r`, `mv`, `copy`, `delete`, `rm -rf` to call from C program.
What is the best way?
To call these command by calling the `system()` call or by writing by myself these functionality?

Comment: What do you need to do with these commands? Simply display their output?

Comment: A lot of basic unix commands are essentially big wrappers for system calls via the C library, e.g. `rm` calls `unlink`. If your commands are simple, it may be easier just to make the calls directly.

Answer (score 0):

`execv` should work.

```
execv("ls", "-r", NULL);
```

It should work for other commands also(not tested though)

[Link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execv.htm)

Comment: Do you maybe about some C API library that gives these system calls mv, copy, delete, ect..  ?

Answer (score 0):

I would re-code them, as I'm interested in learning how to do that. But it's way much more work than calling them via `system(3)`. You also can use `rename(2)` and other system calls as you need them.

So if you want to do it quickly, use `system(3)`; else, have fun :)

**Edit:**

My advice: do it with `system(3)` or `exec*(3)` at first (so you can benefit from the already-implemented features, like `-r`, from the binaries you use), and when you have finished the rest of your program, you can have fun improving that.

Comment: Like exmaple for ll -r I need to list the directory recursively.